# Datastructure for year-month organization

Tags: java, data-structures

What is the best data structure for save information linked by year/month?

I need something like that:

```
2018
    01 -> name      |
          desc      | --> 2018 January data
          time      |
          distance  |

    02 -> name      |
          desc      | --> 2018 February data
          time      |
          distance  |
    ...

2017
    01 -> name      |
          desc      | --> 2017 January data
          time      |
          distance  |
    ...
```

I would like to access the data like that:

```
data["2018"]["01"]
```

I am working with Java and I was thinking to use a linked list with items that are linked list too. What is the more efficient approach?

Comment: how about something like a HashMap<String, Object>, the string can be of the form "2018-01" and the object could have a class object with the name, desc, time, distance in it

Comment: Because I later need extract data by month in a year and by year. For instance, get the total distance in a year.

Comment: yep so you could use something like search.getKey().startsWith("2018"), that would give you all data for the year of 2018. Or even something like search.getKey().contains("-01") which would return all keys for the month of January for all years

Comment: OK... sound great. Thank you.